# xmlplulsar is not working in android

Tags: java, android

I have a code in xml pulsar and it's not working somehow... here is the main parser.

```
URL url;
ArrayList<String> headlines = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList();
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    // Initializing instance variables


    try {
        url = new URL("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk");

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        // We will get the XML from an input stream
        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

        boolean insideItem = false;

        // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                    }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                insideItem = false;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return headlines;
}


public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
    try {
        return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> heads()
{
    return headlines;
}
```

}

and here is the activity code

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (AppStatus.getInstance(this).isOnline()) {

        Log.v("Home", "############################You are online!!!!");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Your online!!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayList<String> headlines = new ArrayList<>();

        externalParser getXML = new externalParser();
        getXML.execute();
        headlines = getXML.heads();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, headlines);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } else {

         Toast.makeText(this,"You are not online!!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("Home", "############################You are not online!!!!");
    }
```

when I run my app the toast/log always says offline and it does not show parsed xml...

here is my manifest

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
> ```

and here is the class that check if it's connected to internet...

> NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
>               connected = networkInfo != null &&  networkInfo.isConnected();
>               return connected;

even if I switch the emulator internet off and on it does not make any difference in app... it always says i'm offline...even when I can brows internet in browser of emulator.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Works fine and returns true in case of internet connected.

```
public boolean isConnected() {
        boolean connected = false;
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);;
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }
```

Secondly once it returns true and you enter into method, you should populate your adapter in onPostExecute() of your AsyncTask or at least call adapter.notifydatasetchanged() in onPostExecute() to make sure your adapter is getting a list with some data you fetched from server in doInBackground(objects params[]... ).

Comment: Hello, i'm always getting intenret not available with above code but when I check internet it looks okay I can browser in emulator... secondly can you point out in my code where should I initialize adapter.notifydatasetchanged()  I got confused as i'm new in this thanks

Comment: Hello the connection part is fixed I added     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> in manifest which fixed connection issue... but can't make the feed to work it does not return anything as listview.

Comment: first check if you are getting response in your doInBackground method (you can after while loop and check your array's length) of your AsyncTask. Secondly in the

Comment: secondly add 
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      delegate.processFinish(result);
    }

Comment: sorry for above two incomplete comments.`@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String param) {
      adapter.notifyDataSetaChanged();
    }`  this method calls on your UI thread once doInBackground completes its work. you can set adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() here.

Comment: Hello thank... but these are completely two classes... the main activity which have GUI and the parser on it's own class... like parser.class and main.class   ... so if I add adapter on the parser.class it won't recognize the adapter...

Comment: you can pass the adapter in constructor as parameter when you instantiate your second class in main activityit. 
like in your mainActivity, `SecondClass second = new SecondClass(adater)`.